# Trouble getting variable read out of a thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

So I'm trying to write a program that looks for keyboard presses and then does something in the main program based upon what the user inputs. I'm trying to run the keyboard listening in a thread and then compare whats in the variable in my main loop, but I don't ever seem to be getting the threaded keyboard input. In the below code, the print maybe updating line never happens, just the else block from the main while loop. What do i need to do so that my main loop is aware of the keys pressed by the user?

```
import threading
import time

kbdInput = ''
playingID = ''

def kbdListener():
    global kbdInput
    kbdInput = rawInput()
    print "maybe updating...the kbdInput variable is: ",kbdInput

listener = threading.Thread(target=kbdListener)

while True:
    print "kbdInput: ",kbdInput
    print "playingID: ",playingID
    if playingID != kbdInput:
        print "Recieved new keyboard Input. Setting playing ID to keyboard input value"
        playingID = kbdInput
    else:
        print "No input from keyboard detected. Sleeping 2 seconds"
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Since you already got your thread started. I will mention that you should consider using a queue if you are going to be doing any multi-threading communication.  Not only will this solve your problem, but it will save you a lot of headaches. Here is the link: [queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)

Comment: So I'm trying to understand what you mean by solve my problem...are you talking about the fact that raw_input() is blocking further execution? I just want to confirm that we're on the same page, because queues seem  abit complicated for a novice like me and I want to be sure that this should address my blocking problem

Comment: Ahh, ok got it. I think I misunderstood your question at first. Yes, A queue is indeed a little advanced, before we go any further though this would be better to open a new question. with the same code, so that you can get more focused help on the new problem. It may be a good idea to also mention that you are a "novice" so that others don't make suggestions that _may_ be too advanced for your current comfort level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the listener by calling `listener.start()` after creating the `listener`.

```
listener = threading.Thread(target=kbdListener)
listener.start()
```

Comment: Ok, I have a follow on to this, is it possible for the raw_input() to not interrupt the flow of the main while loop? it seems to stop and wait for me to type something, but ideally i want the main loop to chug along and just react when it does hear some update from the raw_input thread...is this doable?

Comment: When I run your program on my Mac, the main thread doesn't wait on `raw_input()`. It keeps executing the loop with 2 second sleep.